# Python sys.argv negative argument index

Tags: python, argv, sys

Why should sys.argv with a negative index allow printing same value as sys.argv[0]? That too, it allows this up to number of arguments passed.

So, a call to hello.py at developers.google.com, such as the one below (with 3 arguments including script name) :  python hello.py Sumit Test

would allow accessing sys.argv[-1], [-2] and [-3] with all of them printing the same value as argv[0] i.e. hello.py, but argv[-4] will throw the expected error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "hello.py", line 31, in main
    print (sys.argv[-4])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code is:

```
import sys

# Define a main() function that prints a little greeting.
def main():

  # Get the name from the command line, using 'World' as a fallback.
  if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    name = sys.argv[1]
  else:
    name = 'World'
  print ('Hello', name)
  print (sys.argv[-3])

# This is the standard boilerplate that calls the main() function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: I can't understand this part "sys.argv[-1], [-2] and [-3] with all of them printing the same value as argv[0]". how cant his be for "python hello.py Sumit Test" they should be 'Test' 'Sumit' 'hello.py' correspondingly.

Comment: @olrg - I edited the question to insert the code in it. The line print (sys.argv[-3]) is the one I am referring to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are passing only *three* arguments, my example below should help you  understand:

```
>>> [1,2,3][-1]   # working 
3
>>> [1,2,3][-2]   # working 
2
>>> [1,2,3][-3]   # working 
1
>>> [1,2,3][-4]   # exception as in your code 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Negative index prints a value from the right hand side.

[Accessing Lists](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm#accessing)
For instance our array/list is of size *n*, then for positive indices `0` is the first index, `1` the second and the last index will be `n-1`. For negative indices, `-n` is the first index, `-(n-1)` second, last negative index will be `–1`.

On the basis of your comment, I am adding an example for clarification:

```
import sys
# main()    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print len(sys.argv)
    print sys.argv[-1], sys.argv[-2], sys.argv[-3]
    print sys.argv[0],  sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
```

Please observe the output:

```
$ python main.py one two 
3
two one main.py
main.py one two
```

The number of arguments passed is three. `argv[-1]` is the last argument, which is `two`

Comment: @RichieHindle and Grijesh - Thank you for the answers. But in that case, -1 should return the last argument passed and not argv[0]. The same would be true of -2 and -3 also? 

So, when I run the program as:
python hello.py Sumit test, then argv[0] is hello.py and as per the answers argv[-1] should be "Test", but it prints "hello.py". The same is true of argv[-2] and [-3]

Comment: @sumit yes `argv[-1]` = last argument, check updated answer with example

Answer (score 1):

Negative indexes count from the end of the list:

```
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c'][-1]
'c'
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c'][-2]
'b'
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c'][-3]
'a'
```

Asking for [-4] would go off the end of the list, giving an exception.